# Unable to click on button placed over WindowsFormsHost Control

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost

I have a WindowsFormsHost Control over which I have placed a button. However, I am unable to click the button. I ensured that the button's IsEnabled property is set to True. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087835/can-i-overlay-a-wpf-window-on-top-of-another/6452940#6452940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as the 'airspace' issue. WindowsFormsHost controls will *always* be rendered over WPF controls. Supposedly this will be fixed in a future release according to [this article](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2010/11/wpf-vnext-microsoft-will-solve-airspace.html).