# true wpf webbrowser and .unity3d files. Is it possible?

Tags: .net, wpf, web, unity-game-engine, awesomium

I am in hope of enlightenment on the following scenario.

I deployed a unity 3d scene as a webplayer. This basically creates a html page which loads a .unity3d file. I can then take I.E., chrome and firefox and display the scene.

However, when I try using wpf browsers like awesomium and cefsharp it will not load. Even though they are suppose to be wrappers around the webkit.

Now I could use the stock webbrowser available as a usercontrol in visual studio. Except.. it suffers from the "airspace" problem and unfortunately I need to draw on top of it.

My question. Is there a wpf compliant webbrowser that can render .unity3d files? If so, please point me in the right direction.

Thank you kindly,

Answer (score 1):

Awesomium browser won't load your unity 3d web player. You can still use WPF default web browser in your XAML (`<WebBrowser></WebBrowser>`). For your air space problem. this link will help you a lot : [Can I overlay a WPF window on top of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087835/can-i-overlay-a-wpf-window-on-top-of-another)

Answer (score 0):

Awesomium and the chromium embedded framework, in the context you're using them, are windowless renderers.

Unless support for a particular browser plugin is provided by the developers of your chosen renderer (Flash and Silverlight are supported by Awesomium and I presume CEF too) embedded plugins will not render to the pixel buffer you receive back from that renderer.

If your client machine has the Internet Explorer Unity3D plugin installed then the `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` class should be able to render the Unity Web Player ActiveX context without hassle. Also you could look at embedding the Unity ActiveX control directly [see this article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx) for how to do this and simply change the component to Unity instead of Windows Media Player.

If you do embed an ActiveX context, make sure to set the destination .unity3d source file in the properties window and not with code, otherwise it will not work.