# Detect when/if a popup has decided to re-position itself

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, popup

Okay, for those that aren't familiar with how a WPF popup behaves, this is what is naturally occurs when a popup tries to appear in a place that hasn't got the space to take all of it (such as the edge of a window)...

[image]

Now I have *no problem* with this occurring, my issue is that I'd like to know **when** this has happened, either through an event, or a property, or literally anything - I just need to know **when** the popup has decided "oh there isn't enough space for me, I'm going to move up here instead"

How would I achieve this detection?

Answer (score 1):

No simple way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4632796/7722174

You need to ask yourself 'why do i want to know this' and maybe you'll find
you can do something completely different, for example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743607(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Okay, I'll leave this an open question for now if there's no clear answer and find another more pragmatic way around the issue.